# How to play googledrive .avi format video in jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, video, google-drive-api, streaming, jwplayer

I am working on playing the googldrive video which is in .avi format in jwplayer. I have played mp4 videos but I am unable to play .avi,mkv,wmv format videos in the jwplayer. is ther any way that makes it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, those formats are not supported on the web